# How do I set up a cron job on Snappy?

Tags: cron, ubuntu-core, schedule

If I run

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I can edit the crontab, but it's read-only so nothing gets saved.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, you can't edit the crontab in Snappy Ubuntu Core. Personally I just create a service that sleeps. For instance, say there was an operation you wanted to run every 15 minutes. Put it in a shell script named `my_service.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    do_my_thing
    sleep 15m
done
```

Make it executable. Now create something like the following `snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: foo
version: 1
summary: My snap
description: My snap

apps:
  my-service:
    command: my_service.sh
    daemon: simple

parts:
  foo:
    plugin: copy
    files:
      my_service.sh: bin/
```

If you install the resulting snap you'll have that service with `do_my_thing` running every 15 minutes. If your timing requirements are more complicated (e.g. run every Sunday at 0200) you can still pull this off, but it of course gets a bit more complex.